# Video streaming fails over rtp protocol

Tags: networking, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, video-streaming

Video streaming between Unix Server (ffmpeg) and Windows client (vlc) completed without errors.

*Server side:*

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -r 25 -i /dev/video0 http://192.168.1.114:27018/feed1.ffm
```

*Client side:*

vlc player: Media -> Open Network Stream: `http://192.168.1.114:27018/test.swf`

However, video streaming has approximately 10 s. delay. For this reason, I tried using rtp instead http, but without result. Specifically, on server side I run:

`ffmpeg -f v4l2 -r 25 -i /dev/video0 rtp://192.168.1.114:27018/feed1.ffm`
After the stream begun, on client side I typed: `rtp://@:27018` but it doesn't respond.

What I am missing? Is there any other way I could avoid delay?

*EDIT:*

vlc player's messages (Verbosity: 2 Debug) *(new port used: 27020)*:

```
main debug: adding item `rtp://:27020' ( rtp://@:27020 )
qt4 debug: Adding a new MRL to recent ones: rtp://@:27020
main debug: processing request item: rtp://:27020, node: null, skip: 0
main debug: rebuilding array of current - root Playlist
main debug: rebuild done - 1 items, index 0
main debug: starting playback of the new playlist item
main debug: resyncing on rtp://:27020
main debug: rtp://:27020 is at 0
main debug: creating new input thread
main debug: Creating an input for 'rtp://:27020'
main debug: meta ok for (null), need to fetch art
main debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\Demetres\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher\tvrage.luac
main debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB, in path 'C:\Users\Demetres\AppData\Local\Temp'
main debug: `rtp://@:27020' gives access `rtp' demux `' path `@:27020'
main debug: using meta fetcher module "lua"
main debug: creating demux: access='rtp' demux='' location='@:27020' file='\\@:27020'
main debug: removing module "lua"
main debug: searching art for rtp://:27020
main debug: looking for access_demux module matching "rtp": 12 candidates
main debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
main debug: net: opening any datagram port 27020
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\Demetres\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
main debug: using access_demux module "rtp"
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
main debug: looking for meta reader module matching "any": 2 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\Demetres\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\reader
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\reader
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\reader\filename.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
main debug: no meta reader modules matched
main debug: `rtp://@:27020' successfully opened
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
main debug: no art finder modules matched
main debug: art not found for rtp://:27020
qt4 debug: IM: Setting an input
```

Comment: what do you get if you add the debug option to your command. ffmpeg -loglevel debug -f v4l2 -r 25 -i /dev/video0 rtp://192.168.1.114:27018/feed1.ffm

Comment: `121 frames successfully decoded, 0 decoding errors
[AVIOContext @ 0x78330] Statistics: 0 seeks, 180 writeouts`. I guess that client has the issue. In case it helps I run VLC media player 2.1.3.

Comment: have you had a look in the log of the VLC also? ( vlc-log.txt place in the VLC's Application Directory) What does it say there?

Comment: I didn't find this file. I edited my question with vlc player's messages. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Going from HTTP to RTP is not going to fix a 10 second delay in your video.  The difference you'll see will be on the sub-second level, if you see any difference at all.  You've probably got something else going on that's causing the 10 second delay.

Comment: @heavyd I 'm working on it but still no result. I suspect that udp instead tcp in Transport layer (if this is possible) could solve the problem, or changing video codec with another. Any help would be appreciated.